# Ошибка 500 в самописном MVC фреймворке

Tags: php, mvc, http-status-code-500

Проблема вот в чем: на локалке у меня стоит самописный MVC фреймворк, который там спокойно открывается, при переносе на обычный хостинг в `index.php` на строчке `require '../config/aliases.php'` появляется ошибка 500, это зависит от хостинга или что-то у меня не так?
В корне расположен лишь `.htaccess` файл, где прописано следующее:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|php|png|jpg|bmp|gif|PNG|svg|docx|webp)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php
```

в `public/index.php` прописан код для дальнейшей обработки url-ов и вывода соответствующих страниц:

```
<?php
session_start();

require '../app/lib/dev.php';
$config = require '../config/config.php';

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class.'.php');
    $path = '../app/'.$path;
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require $path;
    }
});

require '../config/aliases.php';

$pconfig = new Config($config);

$router = new Router;
$router->run();
```

aliases.php:

```
$aliases = [

    "core\Controller" => "Controller",
    "core\Model" => "Model",
    "core\View" => "View",
    "core\Router" => "Router",
    "core\Config" => "Config",
    "core\App" => "App",

];

foreach ($aliases as $orig => $alias) {

   class_alias($orig, $alias);

}
```

Comment: Сам апач киает вас в правильную директорию?

Comment: Сейчас построчно проверил работу, выяснилось что редирект работает исправно, проблема начинается со строчки `require '../config/aliases.php';` в `index.php`, где применяется функция `class_alias`, с ней проблемы какие-то

Comment: Какая версия PHP на локалке, какая на хостинге?

Comment: Советую проверить пути, скорее всего у вас там статика, пользуйтесь константой __DIR__ для определения полного пути

Comment: На хостинге PHP 5.6.40, у меня 7.4.8. Что касаемо путей, у меня везде прописаны относительные пути, сменил `..` на `dirname(__DIR__)`, как посоветовали ниже, но проблема осталась та же